# Category Archive not working for pages

Tags: wp-query, categories, pages, taxonomy

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have used this function:

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {

 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );
 if ( ! is_admin() ) {
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_and_tag_archives' );

 }
function category_and_tag_archives( $wp_query ) {
$my_post_array = array('post','page');

 if ( $wp_query->get( 'category_name' ) || $wp_query->get( 'cat' ) )
 $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $my_post_array );


}
```

It adds categories to my WordPress pages, but the category archive pages won't display. I have a category called *Association Landing Pages* with the slug `association-landing-pages`. I am developing locally. When I go to `localhost/mywordpressitefolder/association-landing-page` I am getting a page/file not found error.

Comment: Save permalink and try again and make sure .htaccess is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code did work for me; I was able to see pages under the category archive for *Association Landing Pages* at `http://domain.com/category/association-landing-pages`.

It sounds like you need to use the URL:

```
localhost/mywordpressitefolder/category/association-landing-pages
```

I noticed that you said that the slug was `association-landing-pages` and then you visited `localhost/mywordpressitefolder/association-landing-page` (without the **s**). Make sure to use the right URL based on your slug, and add `/category` too, as explained above.

I would also suggest putting your `is_admin()` check inside the `category_and_tag_archives()` function. I made a couple of other tweaks to the original code too:

```
function add_taxonomies_to_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomies_to_pages' );

function category_and_tag_archives( $wp_query ) {
    $my_post_array = array( 'post', 'page' );

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_category() && $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', $my_post_array );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_and_tag_archives' );
```